# RSpec and Capybara: how to let have_css with text: ignore line breaks in text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have just upgraded my Rails app from Rails 5 to 6.

Now the following assertion doesn't work anymore:

```
expect(page).to have_css '.active a', text: "Reports (1)- current menu item"
```

The error:

```
expected to find visible css ".active a" with text "Reports (1) - current menu item" within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="div" path="/HTML/BODY[1]/MAIN[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]"> but there were no matches. Also found "Reports (1)\n- current menu item", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

So it seems that Capybara cares about line breaks now within link texts...? I can fix it using:

```
expect(page).to have_css '.active a', text: "Reports (1)\n- current menu item"
```

But that feels strange to me. Can anyone explain me what's new here and how to deal with this situation? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what version you were using prior to your upgrade but in 3.0.0  [this commit](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/commit/0c43bfbd3c0d8c240fd50207e6aacb4da8142bed#diff-62800ce7873e3595b33e866277965c69379cd632d093c419072bfc4de579fd47) was introduced and seems to be what you are referring to. *"Visibile text whitespace is no longer fully normalized in favor of being more in line with the WebDriver spec for visible text"* [see here](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md#changed-11)

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 3 Capybara attempts to match text as it's displayed - that means if the text being displayed has a <br> in it, or is partially wrapped inside a block element, etc. then the text will have a linefeed in it.

How to deal with the situation depends on what you're trying to do. By default the `text` option matches substrings so if you don't really care about the full text you can do

```
expect(page).to have_css('.active a', text: 'current menu item')
```

you can also specify a regexp for the `text` option

```
expect(page).to have_css('.active a', text: /Reports (\d+)/)
```

or as you've shown you can add the \n to verify the text as displayed

Comment: That's very interesting. I will have to see whether I used `display: block` for some of the contained text elements.